# including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended! ERROR

Tags: ruby, selenium, rubygems, capybara

including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!

My Gemfile has:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'cucumber'
gem 'rake'
gem 'gherkin'
gem 'testgen'
gem 'rack'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'pry'
gem 'capybara'
```

My env file has:

```
require 'cucumber'
require 'rake'
require 'gherkin'
require 'testgen'
require 'rack'
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'pry'
require 'capybara/DSL'


include Capybara::DSL
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

Capybara.default_wait_time = 10

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of easy ways of fixing this.

The first is to include the following:

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
```

That adds Capybara::DSL and RSpec::Expectations to the world.

The other way is to include this:

```
World(Capybara::DSL)
```

I use the first method, but it's up to you! Both work and will enable you to use Capybara's methods in your tests.

Answer (score -2):

How about commenting out (or removing) the line:

```
include Capybara::DSL
```